# how to set cookies and lunch URL in application in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, cookies, webview-flutter

I want to launch a URL within a Flutter application and I need to set the destination cookies before opening that URL

I used the webview_flutter package and set the cookies in it but had no results

```
`import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:super_app_ok/model/provider/url_bizaji_model.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ProviderProductDefinitionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final UrlBizajiModel settingModel;
  const ProviderProductDefinitionScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.settingModel,
  });

  @override
  State<ProviderProductDefinitionScreen> createState() =>
      _ProviderProductDefinitionScreenState();
}

class _ProviderProductDefinitionScreenState
    extends State<ProviderProductDefinitionScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var sessionCookie1 = WebViewCookie(
      name: widget.settingModel.cookies![0].name!,
      value: widget.settingModel.cookies![0].value!,
      domain: widget.settingModel.cookies![0].domain!,
    );

    var sessionCookie2 = WebViewCookie(
      name: widget.settingModel.cookies![1].name!,
      value: widget.settingModel.cookies![1].value!,
      domain: widget.settingModel.cookies![0].domain!,
    );
    log(sessionCookie1.toJson());
    return WebView(
      initialCookies: [
        sessionCookie1,
        sessionCookie2,
      ],
      "initialUrl": https://devbpm...,
      
    );
  }
}
`
```